# Why doesn't the Paris agreement cover emissions from international shipping?

Tags: international, climate-change, transportation, paris-agreement

Why doesn't the Paris agreement include emissions from international shipping?

According to the [International Maritime Organization (IMO)](https://www.imo.org/en/MediaCentre/HotTopics/Pages/Reducing-greenhouse-gas-emissions-from-ships.aspx):

> Note: The Paris Agreement on climate change was agreed in 2015 by
> Parties to the United Nations Framework Convention on Climate Change
> (UNFCCC) and entered into force in 2016. The Paris Agreement central
> aim is to strengthen the global response to the threat of climate
> change by keeping a global temperature rise this century well below 2
> degrees Celsius above pre-industrial levels and to pursue efforts to
> limit the temperature increase even further to 1.5 degrees Celsius.
> **The Paris Agreement does not include international shipping, but IMO,
> as the regulatory body for the industry, is committed to reducing
> greenhouse gas emissions from international shipping.**

I've been reading about this and was surprised that countries can pollute as much in international shipping and still meet their Paris agreement obligations. Is there a reason why this wasn't included? It seems odd given that there are so many ships sailing between countries and the numbers keep growing.

Comment: Well, one of the problems might be that it gets tricky whom to attribute certain amounts of emissions to - the country where the ship is registered? The country where the ship owners are located (might be multiple)? The countries where the ports are? The coutries where the producers or consumers of the shipped products are? Etc.

Comment: These were left to IMO and ICAO to "regulate" https://www.pbl.nl/sites/default/files/downloads/pbl-2020-analysing-international-shipping-and-aviation-emissions-projections_4076.pdf although the targets appear to have been rather aspirational.

Comment: It's not a surprise it lacks any requirements on shipping as the entire accord is a bunch of toothless promises with no actual legal enforcement provisions.